# Extraction of multiple rows depending on first cell

Tags: google-sheets

please I have this data table bellow

[image]

I want to go to another sheet, insert the transaction ID that I want to extract and extract them like this :

[image]

Can someone help me with this please

The link to the google sheets :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TZYo641Av4SHaHLjSPuAZv3DSnVw0pqSubbtsiYw8Uk/edit#gid=1267341482

Comment: You can help those here to better help you by sharing a link to a spreadsheet with the data from your post already entered. Otherwise, the volunteer contributors here would need to open a sheet of their own and manually enter all of your data before they could even start helping you. It usually speeds things up if you set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: The spreadsheet you provided is private. Can you make it publicly accessible?

Comment: Done, sorry I didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number ID:**

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula({IF('Original sheet'!C:C="",,LOOKUP(ROW('Original sheet'!A:A),IF('Original sheet'!A:A="",,ROW('Original sheet'!A:A)),'Original sheet'!A:A)),'Original sheet'!A:D}),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1="&TEXTJOIN(" or Col1=",TRUE,A2:A))
```

**Text ID:**

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula({IF('Original sheet'!C:C="",,LOOKUP(ROW('Original sheet'!A:A),IF('Original sheet'!A:A="",,ROW('Original sheet'!A:A)),'Original sheet'!A:A)),'Original sheet'!A:D}),"select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1='"&TEXTJOIN("' or Col1='",TRUE,A2:A)&"'")
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, the only problem is that when the ID of transaction contains a letter like 876D87 it wont work. Do you have a workaround that please ?

Comment: I modified the sheet a little bit to be closer to my exact situation where the id contains letters

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: I get : Formula parse error

Comment: Typo, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: It works now but It didn't import any data in the new table ( I changed the column and the selected col ... )

Comment: You changed it wrongly that's why it is not working. I have corrected the formula in the sheet.

Comment: I saw the formula in the sheets but it didn't import all the data required. It only imported the first line of each transaction

Comment: Updated in the sheet. Please check.

Comment: Now it's perfect, thank you sir, thank you so much